# How to dynamically decorate a class?

Tags: c#, decorator, castle-dynamicproxy

I've got a simple decorator class like the following.  Notice how my public methods all create a new instance of the to-be-decorated class, then forward the call to that instance.

The problem with this class is that whenever `IMyService` gets updated, I have to update this proxy class too.

```
public class MyProxyService : IMyService
{
    readonly IMyServiceFactory _realServiceFactory;

    public MyProxyService(IMyServiceFactory realServiceFactory)
    {
        _realServiceFactory = realServiceFactory;
    }

    private IMyService CreateRealService()
    {
        return _realServiceFactory.CreateRealService();
    }

    public int A()
    {
        return CreateRealService().A();
    }

    public int B(int b1)
    {
        return CreateRealService().B(int b1);
    }

    public int C(int c1, int c2)
    {
        return CreateRealService().C(c1,c2);
    }

    public int D(int d1, int d2, int d3)
    {
        return CreateRealService().D(d1,d2,d3);
    }
    public void E()
    {
        CreateRealService().E();
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a dynamic version using `Castle.DynamicProxy`, without any luck so far.

Anyone know a good, simple way to dynamically create a decorator like this?

Comment: Well, dynamic proxy is a good way to go.  Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I find decorator patter very effort consuming and quite not rewording especially if interfaces match 1:1 like in your case. Could you please provide a little background why you require such proxy what is your scenario and your problem. I know this is not necessary for an answer to your question but I would like to know.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I don't really know what I'm doing with DynamicProxy, so I can't show any useful code.  I tried creating an interceptor and changing its invocation target upon interception, but InvocationTarget is read only.

Comment: @Rafal: I use them for all sorts of things, and the idea behind the code above is lazy loading objects and lazy loading remote service proxies.  It works great, but I'd rather not need to change my decorator every time the service interface changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using `DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator`'s [CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(..)](http://kozmic.net/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-x-interface-proxies-with-target/) .

I first created a dynamic proxy factory.  This returns a proxy object, for which each method will be intercepted by the provided `IInterceptor`:

```
public class MyDynamicallyDecoratedServiceClientFactory
{
    readonly ProxyGenerator _proxyGenerator;
    readonly IInterceptor _interceptor;
    public MyServiceClientFactory(IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        _interceptor = interceptor;
        _proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
    }
    public IMyService Create()
    {
        IMyService proxy = _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface<IMyService>(null, _interceptor);
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

I then implemented the interceptor.  Upon each method call, this interceptor will be called, which will create a new `IMyService` from the provided `IMyServiceFactory`, and delegate the method call to that new instance.

```
public class MyServiceClientInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    readonly IMyServiceFactory _svcFactory;
    public MyServiceClientInterceptor(IMyServiceFactory svcFactory)
    {
        _svcFactory = svcFactory;
    }
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        IMyService realService = _svcFactory.Create();
        IChangeProxyTarget changeProxyTarget = invocation as IChangeProxyTarget;
        changeProxyTarget.ChangeInvocationTarget(realService);
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Finally, to make use of all this:

```
// Create a service factory (the to-be-decorated class)
IMyServiceFactory myRealServiceFactory = /* ... */;

// Create a factory that will create decorated services
MyServiceClientInterceptor interceptor = 
        new MyServiceClientInterceptor(myRealServiceFactory);
MyDynamicallyDecoratedServiceClientFactory svcFactory =  
        new MyDynamicallyDecoratedServiceClientFactory(interceptor);

// Create a service client
IMyService svc = svcFactory.Create();

// Use it!
svcProxy.A();
```